# wagtail pagination, django, wagtail, python

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I would be very grateful if someone can help me out on this. I am developing a wagtail site but am short on configuring pagination which when clicking through (ie it just returns the page but not the results), so I have pagination working but when I click, it just returns the page number but does not return the actual model. My code is this:

```
from django.core.paginator import EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger, Paginator

class BlogIndexPage(RoutablePageMixin, Page):
introduction = models.TextField(
    help_text='Text to describe the page',
    blank=True)
image = models.ForeignKey(
    'wagtailimages.Image',
    null=True,
    blank=True,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    related_name='+',
    help_text='Landscape mode only; horizontal width between 1000px and 3000px.'
)

content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
    FieldPanel('introduction', classname="full"),
    ImageChooserPanel('image'),
]
def children(self):
    return self.get_children().specific().live()

def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(BlogIndexPage, self).get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
    all_posts = BlogPage.objects.descendant_of(
        self).live().order_by(
        '-date_published')
    paginator = Paginator(all_posts, 9)

    page = request.GET.get("page")
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context["posts"] = posts
    return context
```

in my html I have the following:

{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load wagtailcore_tags navigation_tags wagtailimages_tags %}

```
{% block content %}
    {% include "base/include/header-index.html" %}

    <div class="col-12">
        {% if tag %}
           
                <p>Viewing all blog posts by <span class="outline">{{ tag }}</span></p>

        {% endif %}

        {% if page.get_child_tags %}
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="blog-tags">
                {% for tag in page.get_child_tags %}
                    <li><a href="{{ tag.url }}">{{ tag }}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>    
        {% endif %}
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            {% if posts.paginator.num_pages > 1 %}
                {% for blog in posts %}
                    <div class="col-3 card__block">
                        <div class="card__content news-blocks">
                            <a href="{% pageurl blog %}">
                                <div class="image">
                                    {% image blog.image fill-850x450-c50 as image %}
                                    <img src="{{ image.url }}" width="{{ image.width }}" height="{{ image.height }}" alt="{{ image.alt }}" class="" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="text">
                                    <h2 class="blog-list-title">{{ blog.title|truncatewords:7 }}</h2>
                                    <p>{{ blog.introduction|truncatewords:15 }}</p>
                                    <span>
                                        {% if blog.date_published %}
                                            {{ blog.date_published }} by 
                                        {% endif %}
                                    
                                        {% for author in blog.authors %}
                                            {{ author }}{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </span>
                                </div>                        
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
                
                {% else %}      
                        <p>Oh, Looks like there is no news currently at the moment. Sorry, please try again at another time.</p>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>


        <!--pagination-->
        {% if posts.paginator.num_pages > 1 %}
        <div class="container">
        
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="pagination">
                    {% if posts.has_previous %}
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <a href="?page={{ posts.previous_page_number }}" class="page-link">
                        <span>&laquo;</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    {% endif %}

                    {% for page_num in posts.paginator.page_range %}
                    <li class="page-item {% if page_num == posts.number %} active{% endif %}">
                        <a href="?page={{ page_num }}" class="page-link">
                        {{ page_num }}
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    {% endfor %}

                    {% if posts.has_next %}
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <a href="?page={{ posts.next_page_number }}" class="page-link">
                        <span>&raquo;</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Much appreciated if anyone can help

Comment: You're retrieving the page number from the URL with `page = request.GET.get("page")`, but then not doing anything with it - you're just fetching page 1 with `paginator.page(1)`.

Comment: Thanks gasman, all needed to do was posts = paginator.page(page) on try, many thanks @gasman